# How to find nearest value that is greater in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I would like to obtain the index of the nearest value in a numpy array which is greater than my search value. Example: `findNearestAbove(np.array([0.,1.,1.4,2.]), 1.5)` should return 3 (the index of 2.).

I know that I can get the nearest index with `np.abs(a-value).argmin()`, and I found out that `min(a[np.where(a-value >= 0.)[0]])` returns the desired array value. Hence, `np.where(a == min(a[np.where(a-value >= 0.)[0]]))[0]` would probably give me the desired index. However, this looks rather convoluted, and I fear that it might break in the case of multi-dimensional arrays. Any suggestions how to improve this?

Comment: And by “nearest” you mean “leftmost”?

Comment: Are your arrays always sorted in ascending order?

Comment: To clarify: "nearest" means "by value". Also: no - the arrays are not necessarily sorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way (I am assuming that by nearest you mean in terms of value not location)

```
import numpy as np

def find_nearest_above(my_array, target):
    diff = my_array - target
    mask = np.ma.less_equal(diff, 0)
    # We need to mask the negative differences and zero
    # since we are looking for values above
    if np.all(mask):
        return None # returns None if target is greater than any value
    masked_diff = np.ma.masked_array(diff, mask)
    return masked_diff.argmin()
```

Result:

```
>>> find_nearest_above(np.array([0.,1.,1.4,2.]), 1.5)
3
>>> find_nearest_above(np.array([0.,1.,1.4,-2.]), -1.5)
0
>>> find_nearest_above(np.array([0., 1, 1.4, 2]), 3)
>>>
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution if the arrays cannot be assumed to be sorted

Comment: Indeed, this is very charming. There is only one little glitch here: if value is larger than the largest array value, then this function returns an index zero. Hence, one needs an extra check: `ind = masked_diff.argmin() ; if my_array[ind]>=target: ind = None ; return ind`. Or is there a more efficient way to fix this?

Comment: `if not np.any(mask): return`

Comment: Thank your for the input, I updated my answer. It works properly now.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for this:

```
In [15]: np.searchsorted(a,[1.5,],side='right')[0]
Out[15]: 3
```

assuming `a` is in ascending order.

This method also won't work for multi-dimensional arrays, but I'm not sure exactly how that use case would work in terms of the expected output. If you could give an example of what you imagine, I might be able to adapt this to that purpose.

*Note*: you could also use [`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) for this purpose, although it executes a linear rather than a binary search, so for certain input sizes, it can be a lot slower than `searchsorted` and requires that `a` be monotonic:

```
In [25]: np.digitize([1.5,], a, right=True)[0]
Out[25]: 3
```

Comment: Thanks! This may turn out to be helpful later when I am indeed dealing with sorted arrays. The use case is that of geographic coordinates: normally they would be 1-dimensional, but you can also have "curvilinear grids", in which case both longitudes and latitudes are stored as 2D arrays. I must admit that I haven't fully thought about the use case for find_nearest_above in this case. It may well be that this doesn't make sense.

Comment: As of v1.10, "np.digitize is implemented in terms of np.searchsorted." (quoting the docs). There is literally no longer a difference between the functions.

Comment: Why when I type `side='left'` it doesn't work opposite way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which worked for me pretty nicely when finding the value and index of the nearest but greater than number in an array (no promises in terms of speed, etc.):

```
def findNearestGreaterThan(searchVal, inputData):
    diff = inputData - searchVal
    diff[diff<0] = np.inf
    idx = diff.argmin()
    return idx, inputData[idx]
```

It's easily adapted for nearest but less than, too:

```
def findNearestLessThan(searchVal, inputData):
    diff = inputData - searchVal
    diff[diff>0] = -np.inf
    idx = diff.argmax()
    return idx, inputData[idx]
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the *right* way to do this:

```
>>> def argfind(array, predicate):
...     for i in xrange(array.shape[0]):
...         if predicate(array[i]):
...             return i
...     return False
...
>>> def find_nearest_above(array, value):
...     return argfind(array, lambda x: x > value)
...
>>> find_nearest_above(np.array([0.,1.,1.4,2.]), 1.5)
  > 3
```

The point here is that if a matching value exists, you'll get the answer when this value is met. Other methods (includeing your own, proposed in the question) will inspect the whole array, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Assuming the arrays *are* indeed sorted, `np.searchsorted` will do this a *lot* faster

Comment: @ali_m yeah, you can be sure, I've heard about binary search. But why do you think that the arrays are sorted?

Comment: well, your solution would *only* work if the arrays are sorted

Comment: @ali_m the thing is that “nearest” for me means “leftmost”. As I've mentioned in a comment to the question.