# Infer nearest, smaller value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array of my_values for which I am trying infer the closest, smaller value in an array of true_values. Using the find_nearest function below doesn't accomplish what I want it to. How can I append this to find the nearest, smaller value?

```
import numpy as np

true_values = np.array([4.5, 3.0, 2.4, 1.2, 0.1])
my_values = np.array([0.8, 2.1, 3.01, 8.0, 0.2, 2.6, 2.1, 3.99, 1.3])

def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = np.abs((array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

nearest = []
for i in my_values:
    nearest.append(find_nearest(true_values,i))

print nearest
# [1.2, 2.4, 3.0, 4.5, 0.1, 2.4, 2.4, 4.5, 1.2]
```

But instead I would like the output to be

```
nearest = [0.1, 1.2, 3.0, 4.5, 0.1, 2.4, 1.2, 3.0, 1.2]
```

The first answer here: [How to find nearest value that is greater in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118350/how-to-find-nearest-value-that-is-greater-in-numpy-array)
accomplishes this for the nearest, larger value. Perhaps this can be changed to find the nearest, smaller value?

Comment: Is `true_values` always sorted?  If so, you might want to look into the `searchsorted` function.

Comment: The other answer you linked can be *very easily* converted to find the nearest, lower value.  Alternatively, you can modify what you already have by insisting that `array-value` is negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `searchsorted` is an option (as mentioned in the comment above and in the one of the answers in the linked question):

```
>>> true_values[-np.searchsorted(true_values[::-1], my_values)]
array([ 0.1,  1.2,  3. ,  4.5,  0.1,  2.4,  1.2,  3. ,  1.2])
```

Note that `searchsorted` requires the `true_values` to be sorted in *ascending* order. Here it's necessary to flip the order of your example array and then make the indices returned into negative integers for the fancy-indexing.

If `true_values` is not sorted (in any direction), you'll need to use `np.argsort` and the `sorter` parameter in `searchsorted`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
true_values[(my_values[:,None] < true_values).argmin(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [33]: true_values
Out[33]: array([ 4.5,  3. ,  2.4,  1.2,  0.1])

In [34]: my_values
Out[34]: array([ 0.8 ,  2.1 ,  3.01,  8.  ,  0.2 ,  2.6 ,  2.1 ,  3.99,  1.3 ])

In [35]: true_values[(my_values[:,None] < true_values).argmin(1)]
Out[35]: array([ 0.1,  1.2,  3. ,  4.5,  0.1,  2.4,  1.2,  3. ,  1.2])
```