# What is causing my linear interpolation to act up?

Tags: python, interpolation

My code for a linear interpolation is functioning strangely.

```
n = np.linspace(t[0],t[-1],101)
print(n)
ypl = np.zeros(len(n))
def closestPoint(x,ydat):
    return ydat[int(round(x))]

def linearInt(T,ydat):
    t0 = round(T+0.01-1)
    y0 = closestPoint(T-1,ydat)
    yn = closestPoint(T,ydat)
    return y0 + (yn-y0)*(T-t0)

for i in range(len(n)):
    if(i != 0):
        ypl[i] = linearInt(n[i],y)

pl.plot(t,y,'o')
pl.plot(n,ypl)
```

The variable t is an array from 0 to 10 with a stepsize of 1. 
The variable y is an array of data points (same size as t).
When I run this code the interpolation runs through all of the points, and looks almost correct, except for the weird spikes. What could be causing this?

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AawFH.png)

Comment: Please post a complete example including some sample data and imports

Comment: You are using `closestPoint` on your `y` data. Shouldn't you use it on your `x` data and read the according values using the index found?

Comment: You know there are functions for linear interpolation in numpy and scipy?

Comment: This topic discusses a numpy way to find the interval a value is in. You can use it to find the upper and lower value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118350/how-to-find-nearest-value-that-is-greater-in-numpy-array

Comment: I do know that there are imports, I just had an assignment to program it myself (and my ta couldn't figure out what was wrong, so I tried here). I'll be able to give a more complete example tomorrow, thanks.